# How to apply texture on a 3D model using drone images with python?

Tags: python, 3d-model, unmanned-aerial-vehicle, texture

I have generated a 3D model in .OBJ format using UAV (drone) images. But this model doesnt have texture so i want to have it textured using the original UAV images. And this should be done in python so that I can include in my original code.

Comment: You need to generate the texture in the photogrametry software you used to process the drone photos. Often this is done automatically but stored in a seperate texture file. (Pix4D for example)